# meld won't start on Cygwin: Complains about the dbus library

Tags: python, cygwin, python3, d-bus, meld

I'm trying to get meld to run on Cygwin 64 (just updated - September 2021), on Windows 10. Some relevant package versions:

- meld: 3.18.0-1
- python3: 3.8.6-1
- python36: 3.6.13-2
- python2: 2.7.18-4

I'm also using MobaXTerm's X server (and it works - I can run xclock for example.)

I've resolved [this initial issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/669847/meld-wont-start-on-cygwin-no-module-named-meld), by running `meld` using Python 3.6. Still, when I try to run meld, this happens:

```
$ meld
process 14421: D-Bus library appears to be incorrectly set up; 
failed to read machine uuid: Failed to open "/etc/machine-id": No such file or directory
See the manual page for dbus-uuidgen to correct this issue.
  D-Bus not compiled with backtrace support so unable to print a backtrace
Aborted (core dumped)
```

How is my d-bus library "incorrectly set up"? How to I correct its setup? And how do I get meld to finally run?

Answer (score 0):

It seems dbus is simply not installed. Install the `dbus` Cygwin package, and meld should work. However, startup time might be long, so wait for it patiently.

You *may or may not* also need to install some of the following additional packages: `libdconf-dbus1-devel`, `libdconf-dbus1_0`, `python-dbus-devel`, `python36-dbus`, `python38-cairo`, `python38-dbus`, `python38-gi`.